# jQuery .load(), I don't want to bind response to a selector

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the code below, but I don't want to have to have the #my_id element exist in the page, I just want to run .load(), like this $.load(), etc... I hope my code explains what I want to do...

```
        $("#my_id").load('/code.php', {'code': code}, function(response, status, xhr){
        if(response == "test"){
            $(this).after(' <img src="/accepted.png" alt="accepted" title="accepted"/>');
        }else{
            $(this).after(' <img src="/not_accepted.png" alt="not accepted" title="not accepted"/>');
            //alert("You typed the following: " + voucher_code);
        }
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
$.post('/code.php', { code: code }, function(response, status, xhr) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Hi, David. Yes it is. But it doesn't seem to work... No ajax request is sent, and no response received...  :(

Comment: I think $.get might be what I'm after.

Comment: @i-CONICA: Normally it should work. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jUVj7/). If something else is wrong we would need more information to be able to help you. Browser inspection tools should be able to let you monitor outgoing requests and see what happens to them.  `$.get` is the same thing as `$.post` but with a different HTTP verb.

Answer (score 0):

Your element must be added to the DOM in order to dispatch the load event. You are also adding some html code using .after() and that works if $(this) is added in the DOM.

I suggest you add your element to the DOM, set it's position somewhere outside the visible area and then run the code. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

this is from load() manual:

Example: Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics

```
$(window).load(function () {   
    // run code 
});
```

---

UPDATE

here is fully working code (this is an example only, proper validation should be considered server and client sides):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).load('code.php', {'code': "bla"}, function(response, status, xhr){
        if(response == "test"){
            $('#d').after(' <span>'+response+'</span>');
        }else{
            $('#d').after(' <span>no</span>');
            //alert("You typed the following: " + voucher_code);
        }
});
</script>

<div id="d"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

code.php:

```
$e = $_REQUEST['code'];

if($e) {
echo 'test';
}
```

output:

```
<body>
<script>
...
</script>

<div id="d"> </div> <span>test</span>

</body>
```